# init.el is not being read at opening by emacs even though it is present in the good directory

Tags: emacs

the init.el file is not being read when Emacs opens, even though it is present and in the correct directory (~/.emacs.d/init.el). I have checked the permissions, and the file is set to read and write. I am using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

I tried some variable and they are not read. The splash sreen still there...

```
;; Don't show the splash screen
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)  ; Comment at end of line!
```

Comment: What does `C-h v user-init-file` tell you?

Comment: What does C-h v user-init-file tell you? ''no match''

Comment: Don't know what to say, this is the result I get. https://cloud-cmdp.yourownnet.cloud/s/iFAq3z5pMCEDtPb

Comment: same result when I run emacs -Q

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake with the command, this is the result : 
Its value is "/home/martin/.emacs"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a mistake with the command, this is the result :

user-init-file is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Its value is "/home/martin/.emacs"

File name, including directory, of user’s initialization file.
If the file loaded had extension ‘.elc’, and the corresponding source file
exists, this variable contains the name of source file, suitable for use
by functions like ‘custom-save-all’ which edit the init file.
While Emacs loads and evaluates any init file, value is the real name
of the file, regardless of whether or not it has the ‘.elc’ extension.

Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 21.1.

Well, I don't know what happened, but my init.el file seems to have been detected and is now being read.

Sorry for the mistake and thanks a lot for your help

Problem solved!

Comment: That explains why it wasn't using `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.  Read https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html to learn more about this.

Comment: I erase the .emacs file, probably it was looking there first.